# Issues with ugly layout in XML-based File format

Tags: android, xml

I started writing a super-simple text adventure game a few months ago, and I am just now getting back to it.  But after looking at the layout, I now think it's really ugly.

I'm really new to this whole XML layout format, and I was wondering if someone could take a look at this for me and let me know if there's a better, more attractive way of writing this layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout android:stretchColumns="*" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center">  

            <TextView android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/introText" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" 
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView android:text="navigationText" 
                android:id="@+id/navigationText" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_margin="2dip"/>

            <TextView android:text="actionText" 
                android:id="@+id/actionText" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_margin="2dip"/>

            <TextView android:text="encounterText" 
                android:id="@+id/encounterText" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_margin="2dip" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"/>
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>  

<TableLayout android:stretchColumns="*" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1a" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="left">    

        <TextView android:text="characterInfo" 
            android:id="@+id/charText" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/textView1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView> 

        <Button android:text="North" 
            android:id="@+id/btnNorth" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="2dip">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
        android:gravity="left">

        <TextView android:text="statsText" 
            android:id="@+id/statsText" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:layout_margin="2dip">
        </TextView> 

        <Button android:text="West" 
            android:id="@+id/btnWest" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dip" android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="2dip" android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:text="i" 
            android:id="@+id/btnInventory" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_marginTop="2dip" 
android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:text="East" 
            android:id="@+id/btnEast" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" android:layout_marginRight="32dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dip" android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
        android:gravity="left">

        <TextView android:text="itemsText" 
            android:id="@+id/itemsText" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/textView2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
        <Button android:text="South" 
            android:id="@+id/btnSouth" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="2dip">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/textView3" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <Button android:text="Attack" android:id="@+id/btnFight" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Flee" android:id="@+id/btnRun" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Search" android:id="@+id/btnSearch" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"></Button>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to make your layout more manageable, there are a number of simple solutions I can think of.  They mostly require zero to little design change.

- You can add XML comments to separate logical sections, as ugly as they may be
- You could divide your layout into separate included layouts
- You can use [fragments](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) (using the Fragment Compatibility Package available through the SDK updater if necessary) to fragment your Activity into separate UI components which would have their own layout files. This is the only solution that would require moving your java code around, but I highly recommend it; it makes UI components highly reusable.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm guessing you mean make the code look better, right? You've asked a general question so the best I can do is give you a general answer. What you should probably do is combine some of these layout elements together into what are called [CompoundControls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound). This will allow you to factor out a bunch of the code in to smaller xml layout files. You'll be basically just creating your own composite widgets that you can then place in your main layout using less code. Plus, you can reuse the widgets in multiple places.

Comment: I guess I'm admitting that I'm not at all familiar with this XML layout format.  I come from websites where I can modify the HTML and CSS...but modifying a layout with XML almost(ok it does) seem tedious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking to make the code look better, the latest version of the ADT Plugin for Eclipse [has an XML layout code formatter](http://tools.android.com/recent/xmlformatter) that reformats your code to the generally accepted Android style.  I find the code it produces looks pretty nice (at least as nice as XML can look).

Answer (score 1):

If what you are writing is a game, you should really consider using a Canvas instead of trying to design a complex layout from Android components. I suggest this page as a way to get started:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Naturally, since your project is text-based, you'd be primarily interested in the primitives and functions that draw text, like drawText() in the Canvas class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html